# django uml database

Tags: database, django, uml

Is there any possibility to export the Django database into some kind of a UML tool, so that i can see graphically see the relations between tables (or even between classes) ?

thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with Django, but with databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [django-extensions](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/) project includes a `modelviz` management command which will export your model structure to .dot (Graphviz) format, which can be printed or imported into Visio or OmniGraffle.

Comment: wow, perfect! thanks so much! (my app is not really ready, but it will be soon, and i'll need this feature)